# Non-Anglicism way of saying “offshore”

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire, anglicismes

I have seen the term “offshore (position)” used either in English or French for describing someone who is working for a company that has its headquarters in a foreign country. Can someone recommend me a "pure French" word or short phrase for describing the same term?

---

J'ai vu le terme « emploi offshore » utilisé en Anglais et en Français pour décrire quelqu’un qui travaille dans une entreprise qui a ses bureaux dans un autre pays. Est-que quelqu'un peut me recommander une autre façon de dire la même chose sans utiliser cet anglicisme ?

Comment: What do you mean by "offshore position"? An offshore job is for people who work in the oil industry. People who work abroad are not said to have "offshore positions" in English. What one sees in English is "offshore company". They work in offshore companies. So: offshore company job.

Comment: @lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshoring

Comment: We don't say offshore position for a overseas job or job abroad. We say to work for an offshore company.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

En français *offshore* est rarement employé en dehors du contexte pétrolier.

En langage courant on dit « situé à l'étranger ». Pour être plus rigoureux on dira : « **extraterritorial** », pour une banque ou le siège d'une entreprise par exemple,  voir plusieurs exemples dans le [GDT](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.aspx).
Pour un emploi on dit plutôt « **délocalisé** ».

Comment: Merci, *délocalisé* c'est le mot que je cherchais. Entre parenthèses, j'ai vu le terme *offshore* utilisé en France et au Québec dans le milieu informatique (développement des logiciels)

Comment: +1 pour *délocalisé*. Dans le milieu du travail, _offshore_ a une connotation que les autres traductions n'ont pas. Quand on parle d'_offshore_ ou de _délocalisation_, on sous-entend coût moindre du travail à l'étranger et perte d'emplois locaux.

Answer (score 5):

Le terme *offshore* est aussi traduit par à *l'étranger* en ce qui concerne les comptes bancaires.

Un compte est généralement qualifié de « compte offshore » s'il est situé dans un pays considéré comme étant un « paradis fiscal ». (Alain Saint-Etienne l'indique en commentaire, et cela me semble effectivement important à préciser !)

Comment: Cette réponse est sans doute hors-sujet. Sinon, il faut la compléter en mentionnant qu'un compte est généralement qualifié de "compte offshore" s'il est situé dans un pays considéré comme étant un "paradis fiscal".

Comment: Vous avez parfaitement raison !

Answer (score 5):

Le terme « **expatrié** » est fréquemment employé en France pour décrire un poste basé à l'étranger, notamment dans un contexte de ressources humaines.

Answer (score 2):

An expression that is sometime used is **outremer** (overseas).

Answer (score 0):

Originellement, c'est **en mer** ou **au large**

avec la possibilité de traduire, même si c'est peu usité

- éolienne offshore, par *éolienne marine*,
- forage offshore par *forage en mer profonde* en opposition à *forage sur le plateau continental*

*Édité pour complément*

Utilisé comme adjectif, la traduction recommandée par le Robert est *en mer* pour ce qui concerne les installations pétrolières.

*Extraterritorialité* concerne les banques, sinon cela concerne l'armée américaine.

*A l'étranger* convient pour les emplois.

***Cigares (des mers)*** peut être utilisé lorsqu'il s'agit de puissants bateaux à moteur de haute mer très rapides et que l'on parle de sport nautique 'OffShore'.

Comment: Non, on ne dirait pas un « emploi au large ». La question ne porte pas sur ce sens du mot *offshore*.

Comment: @Gilles J'ai parlé d'origine, les emplois offshore sont au départ des emplois sur une plate forme pétrolière, donc en mer, ils ont dérivé ensuite en *emploi à l'étranger* d'origine anglaise.